# Are there ferry companies that visit the Norwegian fjords?

Tags: ferries, norway, fjords

I'm interested in visiting Norway's fjords via a round-trip ferry out of Oslo. Are there companies that do this?

Comment: Another variants: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/763/how-to-see-the-norwegian-fjords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oslo is not really a good starting point for visiting the fjords. I assume you are thinking about the deeper fjords?

Some alternatives:

- Hire a car in the northern parts of Norway (Nordland) and follow
  [Kystriksveien](http://www.kystriksveien.no/?lng=en). This will take you along the coast crossing
  several fjords.
- Fly to Bergen and take one of the [nordled](http://eng.norled.no/Default.aspx?pageid=756) ferries or express 
  boats to one of the fjord destinations.

Answer (score 9):

You can check [Hurtigruten](http://www.hurtigruten.com/).

Comment: Hurtigruten starts in Bergen. It doesn't go to Oslo.