# How to see the Norwegian fjords

Tags: budget, planning, netherlands, norway, fjords

I am currently working in The Hague area of the Netherlands. This summer is too cold to spend weekends on the beach, so I've decided to spend 3-4 days seeing the Norwegian fjords instead.

I understand there are three possibilities:

1. Find a ship starting from Amsterdam that goes to the fjords and back.
2. Go to one of the fjords and rent a house for 2-3 days.
3. Go to Oslo or another Norwegian city, stay there, and take a bus trip to the fjords.

Which is the cheapest, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

As for now - the most desired for me is 2. I checked the prices for flights - and Oslo is 3 times cheaper from Amsterdam then Trondheim. Do you know if there is a possibility to rent a house on the fjord close to Oslo?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/755/are-there-ferry-companies-that-visit-the-norwegian-fjords

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hurtigruten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurtigruten) is a passenger line that sails along the Norwegian coast, and the trip has been described as the "World's Most Beautiful Sea Voyage." It costs from €641 for a [6-day voyage](http://www.hurtigruten.com/Norway/Voyages/Classic-Hurtigruten-Voyages/6-days-Kirkenes-Bergen/). The disadvantage of this is that you're stuck on a boat. Earlier this year, the [Norwegian Broadcasting Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Broadcasting_Corporation) **filmed 134 hours of Hurtigruta** and showed it live. Your cheapest option by far is to watch the trip [online](http://nrk.no/hurtigruten/). It will also show you what to expect if you choose this option.

One option would be to go to [Bergen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergen), marketed as the gateway city to the world famous fjords. From there, there are tours going to the fjords, for instance [Hardangerfjorden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardangerfjord), and probably other fjords as well. Hurtigruta also starts here. Note that it rains a lot in Bergen, bring an umbrella.

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I've already browsed couple of possibilities close to Bregen (about 190km by car).

Answer (score 2):

For such a short visit, I would want to do as little surface travel as possible as that is always slower than airtravel.

So I used Skyscanner to have a look at prices Schiphol (AMS) to Bergen (BGO) and when buying now for July or August you will still find prices of about €200 to €300 for a return ticket.

If you love trains, you could fly into Oslo and out of Bergen or the other way around, but it is still about 7 hours train travel, although with a good view of the countryside.  Personally I would wait with that till you have at least a week and combine Oslo with Bergen and the fjords.

A friend of mine who settled in Norway did chose Bergen as it is a nice small town with good access to nature, including the fjords.