# Visit the Norwegian fjords or other attractions when landing in Haugesund

Tags: sightseeing, itineraries, norway, fjords

The airport of Haugesund is currently served by some low cost companies; I tried to discover some attractions of that area but on the guides I only found some lines about the city of Stavanger and almost nothing else.

I was wondering how difficult could it be to visit an interesting Norwegian fjord when landing in Haugesund.

I see from [another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/763/how-to-see-the-norwegian-fjords) that I could travel from Haugesund to Bergen which is considered to be the gateway of the fjords. The problem is that Bergen is roughly two hours from Haugesund.

Is there an easier solution that allows me to spare the transfer to Bergen and visit an interesting fjord? Consider that the journey should be at most four days long.

In case there are no such solutions, are there any other peculiar attractions in the area around Haugesund that doesn't require renting a car?

EDIT: As Tor-Einar Jarnbjo writes in the comment, solutions could be very different depending on when the journey is going to take place. My question is mainly related to the period between late spring (May) and the beginning of the autumn (October).

Comment: When are you planning to go? Public transport to tourist spots is often restricted to the holiday seasons (easter and summer).

Comment: sorry, I'll edit the question in order to specify when I'm planning to go. Anyway, it's going to be between late spring (May) and beginning of autumn (October).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This being western Norway, **fjords are everywhere**.

[image: West Norway]

<sup>West Norway from [Wikimedia Commons](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/File:WestNorway.png)</sup>

If you want to take the bus to Bergen, scroll down. This is probably interesting enough. You might also be interested in taking one of the [coastal speedboats](http://eng.norled.no/Default.aspx?pageid=756) to Bergen or Stavanger. From there you might want to head to spectacular Preikestolen. I recommend reading the [West Norway](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/West_Norway) Wikivoyage article. In summary, there are *plenty* of things to see close to Haugesund!

#### By bus from Haugesund to Bergen

This is not necessarily the most interesting trip to do from Haugesund, but just to illustrate that a bus is not a lost time. The bus ride takes [5½ hours](http://kystbussen.no/Bestilling_steg_2.aspx) whereas a speedboat takes [3¼ hours](http://www.norled.no/uploads/documents/HurtigbaatRuter/Hordland_2013/Flaggruten_Stavanger_Bergen_2013.pdf).
Why does the bus ride from Haugesund to Bergen take so long? *Because the fjords are in the way!*

The trip includes a ferry crossing that alone takes 40 minutes, [see timetable](http://www.fjord1.no/eng/ferry/ferry-timetables/hordaland/sandvikvag-halhjem). So the travel to Bergen is not *to see a fjord*; the travel to Bergen *is part of seeing the fjord*.

Fjords you may see between Haugesund to Bergen:

- Viksefjorden
- [Bømlafjorden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B8mlafjorden)

[image: Bømlafjorden]

<sup>From [Wikimedia commons](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Indre_B%C3%B8mlafjorden-2.jpg)</sup>

- Sagvågsfjorden
- [Langenuen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langenuen), to be crossed by ferry

[image: Langenuen]

<sup>From [Wikimedia commons](http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fil:Langenuen_in_moonlight.JPG)</sup>

- Fusafjorden

That being said, there *are* more famous fjords than the ones between Bergen and Haugesund, and there are probably more interesting journeys than this particular bus ride. But wherever and however you travel, keep in mind that while you are travelling to the next fjord attraction, you will almost certainly be travelling along fjords that are not even considered tourist attractions. They're just there — part of the landscape. As they say in German: *Der Weg ist das Ziel*.