# Can you see Fjords from Bergen as a day trip without a car?

Tags: public-transport, norway, fjords, bergen

I gather a great way to see a lot of the Norwegian Fjords is to head to Bergen, and take cruise from there over several days. I'm pondering a much shorter trip (and hopefully much cheaper too!) to Bergen, and I'm wondering if it might be possible to see at least a little bit of the fjords without a car in just a day?

Are there any buses that will take you to somewhere where you can hike to see the fjords? Or any day trip boats? Or will I need to plan to hire a car if I want to get out of the city to see the fjords?

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13681/2509).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily, just go for the [Norway in a Nutshell](http://www.norwaynutshell.com/en/explore-the-fjords/norway-in-a-nutshell/) route:

> You can experience the scenic Bergen Railway, the breathtaking Flåm Railway, the Aurlandsfjord, the narrow Nærøyfjord and the steep hairpin bends of Stalheimskleiva (May-September).

The link above is to a commercial tour agency who will arrange the whole thing if you want (8.5 hours end to end), but you can quite easily do it by yourself, especially from Bergen.  Just plan ahead by checking out the train and ferry schedules, as they don't run all that often...  and consider overnighting along the way, so you can catch some bits without all the other tourists doing the N-in-a-N loop!

Comment: Planning a "Norway in a Nutshell" trip yourself will also make it a lot cheaper, in many cases, especially if you are eligible for student discounts.